# How to auto mount my external hard drive?

Tags: 10.10, usb, mount, usb-drive, automount

On login, ubuntu **10.10** would not mount external hard drives automatically, While ubuntu **10.04** mount them on login.
I've tried **Storage Device Manager** but it give error when external hard is not plugged.

any idea or suggestion?

Comment: agreed with Takkat. ytg: you do need fstab for this. You learn by messing up! You also learn to create backups if you mess up so start with that ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm in a similar situation, except that my system worked just fine with 10.04. I have an external mybook hard drive that I use for backup using nfs4 and grsync. At the end of fstab I have these mount commands:

```
/media/mybook/laptop_backup /export/laptop_backup none bind 0 0
/media/mybook/laptop_D610 /export/laptop_D610 none bind 0 0
/media/mybook/laptop_www /export/laptop_www none bind 0 0
```

In 10.04, boot completed with these directories mounted and accessible over the network. When I upgraded to 10.10, the boot pauses with an error message regarding each one giving me the option to press S to skip or some other letter to manually fix the problem. Since I don't know how to fix it, I just skip (once for each directory) and boot completes. Manually executing `sudo mount -a` succeeds in mounting the directories. I guess the timing changed from 10.04 to 10.10 or something.

Note that there is no mount command for the mybook external USB 1 TB hard drive in /etc/fstab. So I guess the drive automounted in 10.04 and that's not happening in 10.10. I tried adding:

```
 /dev/sdd1 /media/mybook type ext3
```

But that failed in the same way that mounting the directories did.

Adding the `nobootwait` option fixed it. Oddly, it looks like nobootwait apparently causes the system to wait until the mount is completed, even though the man page says the opposite. Here's the commands from /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sdd1 /media/mybook ext3 nobootwait 
/media/mybook/laptop_backup /export/laptop_backup none bind 0 0 
/media/mybook/laptop_D610 /export/laptop_D610 none bind 0 0 
/media/mybook/laptop_www /export/laptop_www none bind 0 0 –
```

Answer (score 6):

**This is the GUI way of doing it so you don't have to modify your fstab file manually.**

If you look in the repositories you should see a program called [mountmanager](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountmanager) 
 or from the terminal (command line) just type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mountmanager
```

Once it is installed you can open it by clicking System->Administration->Mount Manager from the menus.

**Note:** this program is currently supported till 12.10. It isn't yet available for 13.04.

Once the program is open you can click the extra drive you want to automount from the list on the left.  In the options you have a area where you can pick the mount point. In my case I wanted my external drive to be mounted at `/media/drive/` so I created a directory there and set it as the mount point. Then I clicked partition->apply from the mount manager menus.

Here it stated it would be modifying my fstab file but I clicked okay.  Rebooted my machine and everything was good it was auto-mounted there.

Comment: Warning: I installed this program and ran it. I decided not to use any of its features since the user interface was horrible and I couldn't make heads or tails of it. I decided to close the program not using any of its functionality. To my horror, when I opened /etc/fstab in nano afterward I noticed that it had already rewritten /etc/fstab without my consent.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and it turned out to be that the device had changed for the drive and it was conflicting with the root drive.  After the error the boot process stopped and queried me to type <kbd>S</kbd> to skip and continue or <kbd>M</kbd> to bring up a shell and do a manual fix.

Typing <kbd>M</kbd> and then `mount -a` resulted in a message that the device was already mounted as `/` which was not true.  This was the hint that it was confused.

It is apparently safer to us UUIDs in the fstab than to use device labels as this avoids such conflicts.  You can type "blkid" to find the device to UUID mapping and also see if the device has changed from what you had in the table.

The mountmanager utility allows you to specify labels or UUIDs , so this can be of help if you want to automatically generate the fstab from a GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Basically ubuntu should automount your external harddrive. If it doesnot mount then you can enter the information on /etc/fstab. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) for mounting information.

Comment: it didn't help me :|

Answer (score 2):

Install `ntfs-config` from the package manager and click on auto configure on first start.

[image: This]

Comment: cool! But I do advice everyone to dig into editing /etc/fstab. It is not that hard and at **some** point your gnome/unity is broken and you are left with is a command line prompt. All those changes you made on command line will help you to appreciate command line. (but it is a nifty program ;) )

Comment: This would be a nice one. The original question didn't say, but sadly my partitions aren't NTFS, they are ext4 and ReiserFS.

Answer (score 2):

Editing fstab is really the best way to go.  It is really not a hard as it first appears. Just `cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.orig` and make sure that you have a live cd/usb handy in case you really mess up.

You could also try a script using gvfs-mount, and load it at startup.  It is in the package gvfs-bin if it is not installed by default.  The syntax is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me:

Open the configuration editor and set up

```
/apps/nautilus/preferences/
    media_automount = true
    media_automount_open = true
```

Then install usbmount:

```
sudo apt-get install usbmount
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help but I don't understand your language :)

Answer (score 0):

Comparing different versions of Ubuntu does not work for me. There are always changes and if you upgrade then you accept change. Implicit in such comparisons is that the previous one worked, so the latest must not be as good. In the case of devices, it could be due to many reasons including enhanced security using Apparmor. This could be due to changes at any level including the kernel and may not be due to something Canonical had done.

In my experience, how things mount depends on the file system. If it is FAT32 or NTFS then it usually mounts devices as you attach them. If it is a device that is formatted under Linux then it may have additional permissions that require you to give your password.

I have used K/Ubuntu since 2006 and have not had to edit fstab for the past three years. I have at present four external drives attached with at least a dozen partitions of all different file systems and everything works as expected. One is a brand new Seagate that I did not have to do anything to. i just plugged it in and attached it. If something does not mount there is usually a good reason for it.

It could be that it need a consistency check because it was not removed properly or it has been mounted many times without one. It could be that the device is not connected properly or something such as VirtualBox is using it. It could be that the device has a problem which could be easy to fix or complex. I have several usb sticks. Some work well and others have problems. I have had to throw a couple away over the years while others have had to be re-formatted to get them to work due to something that has happening in use, such as being impatient and removing it too soon or a flag set to make it bootable.

It is hard to generalise based on limited information.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add a line in /etc/fstab with the option "auto" at the end. I'm not at home, else I would copy-paste you my line... I've Ubuntu 10.10 and an external USB hard disk.

Comment: waiting for your codes :)