# How to automount a partition on boot / Como hago para montar un particion al inicio del sistema? 

Tags: 11.10, ntfs, automount

Como hago para montar una particion al inicio del sistema?

Antes en Ubuntu 9.04 lo hacia con el paquete ntfs-config que me instalaba una aplicacion llamada "herramienta de configuracion ntfs" que simplimente realizaba 2 clicks y listo.

Pero esta herramienta ya no funciona en Ubuntu 11.10 y de hecho creo que a partir de la version 10.10 no funciona bien :(

**TRANSLATED**

How do I auto mount a partition on boot?

Before on Ubuntu 9.04 I would auto mount a partition with a package called **ntfs-config** that would install a application called **NTFS Configuration Tool**. With this tool I would auto mount the partition with 2 clicks and done.

But this tool does not work on Ubuntu 11.10 and in fact I think it does not work well since 10.10 :(

Comment: Please read here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/9599/how-to-mount-ntfs-drive-at-startup and here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/10947/how-to-auto-mount-my-external-hard-drive

Por Favor lee aqui - http://askubuntu.com/questions/9599/how-to-mount-ntfs-drive-at-startup y aqui - http://askubuntu.com/questions/10947/how-to-auto-mount-my-external-hard-drive

Con ambos casos podras resolver tu problema.

Comment: related question about ntfs-config -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions/46592#46592

Comment: `pysdm` is a small program that will edit your `fstab` for you.  It's smart about picking the default choices.

Answer (score 3):

you can try also pysdm .

```
sudo apt-get install pysdm
```

and run it: `sudo pysdm`

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it. My need: I dualboot Ubuntu 11.10 and Windows 7, both 64 bit. I use Dropbox for backup and sharing of documents, and wanted to use the same folder/directory on the Windows partition for Dropbox when I was running Ubuntu.

Solution: I installed the GUI application "mountmanager" via Ubuntu Sotware Center. mountmanager was easy to use; I figured out what to do without reading any documentation. I found the windows partition that I was interested in and saved the default configuration set up by mountmanager. Afterwords I had to edit the file /etc/fstab because the name of my partition contained a space character: From "New volume" to "New\040volume" (no quotes in fstab).

Answer (score 1):

lo haces editando el archivo  **/etc/fstab**  con un editor de texto yo uso kde asi que lo agon con kate en ubuntu creo que es leafpad esi que tendrias que correr este comando
**sudo leafpad  /etc/fstab** , y debes saber el nombre  el puto de montage de la particion, eso lo haces corriendo el comando
**sudo fdisk -l**   alli identifica la particion ya sea por tamano o extencion (NTFS) y toma nota del puto de montage
ejemplo: /dev/sda1

puede que necesites instalar  **ntfs-3g**

en el archivo **/etc/fstab** tienes que agregar una linea de la siguiente manera
tomando como ejemplo  que la particion se llama windows y el punto de montage es /dev/sda1
la linea se agrega debajo de una linea que ya existe 
.....los puntos no existen los use nadamas como espaceadores

proc.............../proc.............................proc...............nodev,noexec,nosuid.....0.....0   **esta linea ya existe**

/dev/sda1..../media/windows.....ntfs-3g .........defaults,force....................0.....0 **linea que tienes que agregar**

Nota: esto es nadamas para particiones ntfs (particiones de windows), particiones con otras extenciones la linea es diferente

Esto no es en dos clicks como solias hacerlo, pero es una manera de hacerlo

**TRANSLATED**

you do by editing the file **/etc/fstab** with a text editor I use kde so I do it with kate in ubuntu is leafpad i think it you would have to run this command
**leafpad sudo /etc/fstab** and is you don't know the name of montage point of the partition, that you do run the command
**sudo fdisk-l** identifies the partition there either by size or extention (NTFS) and take notes of the point of montage
example: /dev/sda1

may need to install **ntfs-3g**

in the file **/etc/fstab** you have to add a line as follows
using the example of the partition is called windows and point of montage is /dev/sda1
line is added below an existing line

..... there are no points i use as spacers

**this line already exists**

/ dev/sda1..../media/windows.....ntfs-3g ......... defaults, force .................. .. 0 ..... 0

**line you have to add**

/dev/sda1..../media/windows.....ntfs-3g ........defaults,force....................0.....0

Note: This is only offer for ntfs partitions (Windows partitions) partitions with other line extensions is different

This isn't in two clicks as it used to, but it is a way to do

Comment: Could you please include a translation?

Comment: Despite the flags against this post, I'm going to leave it as-is. The original question was in Spanish so it might prove useful to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it in Ubuntu 11.10:

You'll have to edit the file `/etc/fstab` but will need some information before

Find out the partition's mount point name using `sudo fdisk -l` i.e. `/dev/sda3` and take note of the file system (NTFS, linux etc.). Althoug you may use this mount point, native fstab entries use the UUID, so you can get this using `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`

Create the definitive mount point for the partition. Pick a name for it (i.e. *mydrive*) and create a dir with that name. In Ubuntu mounted partitions use to be in `/media` dir so it is a good practice leave it there. Use `sudo mkdir /media/mydrive` to create it. Change "mydrive" for the name you picked. In my case, whenever I mount my partition manually Ubuntu create the dir `/media/DATA` so I unmounted it and re-created this dir.

Make a backup of your fstab file using `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup` and then `sudo gedit /etc/fstab` to open a text editor. There you'll add a new line. This new line will have five elements separated by TABs: `UUID | dir | flie system | options | flag` so your new line may be:

`UUID=2875A6F278A77F5Z /media/DATA  ntfs-3g defaults    0   0`

where `UUID=XXXXX` is the uuid you get with `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`, `/media/DATA` is the dir you created with `sudo mkdir /media/DATA` and `ntfs-3g` is for NTFS (windows) partitions (you may use ext3 or ext4 if the mounted partition is Linux). Leave columns `defaults 0 0` alone. They will work that way.

Save the file and test it without reboot using `sudo mount -a`. If everything worked, you'll see your new partition mounted and will be there the next time you boot up.

REMEMBER: a) Back up your fstab file! b) Each element of the new line must be separated by tabs or spaces