# How to make partition mounting permanent?

Tags: mount, xubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to auto mount my external hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10947/how-to-auto-mount-my-external-hard-drive)

I have a few partitions on my PC, for example for movies, so when I reinstall the operating system they remain untouched. When installing Xubuntu 12.04 I forgot to set mounting points for these partitions. Now I can mount and unmount them in Thunar manually as if they were USB drives, but that is for the session only, after I restart my computer I have to do it again.

I know that I could just edit `/etc/fstab` but I'm not really a power user of Linux, and I don't want to mess things up, especially with these partitions.

Is there a way (preferably with a program that has a GUI) to just make these manual mounts permanent? And if there is not, then how could I find out what to write for them into the `fstab` to not mess up things?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to auto mount my external hard drive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10947/how-to-auto-mount-my-external-hard-drive) and http://askubuntu.com/questions/2280/selective-mounted-volumes-for-the-gnome-desktop-and-nautilus-sidebar. You want to edit your fstab.